DBeaver - Connecting to RDS instance through an ssh tunnel using AWS SSM
I have some RDS instances accessible through EC2 istances (each RDS has its jump EC2). Currently, I was using DBEaver Community edition to connect to the database configuring an ssh tunnel to the EC2.
For security reason I can't use ssh anymore so the RDS is unreachable from my local machine. I have to use an aws role with SSM authentication.
I have successfully connected to my EC2 opening an SSM tunnel. i have used the following ssh config file.
Host goffy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
HostName i-#########                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
User donald                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --profile my-profile --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"

Now the troubles. i want to use this on DBeaver. i've tried opening a tunnel in localhost with SSM so i can configure the dbeaver connection to tunnel from localhost to the EC2 but it means i have to keep a terminal opened and potentially choose different port for each RDS i own:
aws ssm start-session --target "i-#########" --document-name AWS-StartPortForwardingSession --parameters "portNumber"=["22"],"localPortNumber"=["2222"]

Is it possible to configure DBEaver connection to use the proxy command contained in the .ssh/config file?

This is a feature that is natively supported by DBeaver.
Have a look at this documentation here for detailed instructions: https://dbeaver.com/docs/dbeaver/AWS-SSM-Configuration/
Ultimately DBeaver can handle the AWS authentication, authorization (if required), tunnel setup, and credential persistence for repeat uses.
